# Python 2.7 Trouble with winsound frequency

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm making a program where you enter a list of integers, it changes your integers into notes, and then plays those notes in order. But, if you enter zero and set the frequency to zero, the program crashes. I've tried adding an if statement that changes the frequency to 100 if this happens, but no luck.

the following is my code:

```
import winsound

FREQUENCY = 0
NOTES_PROMPT = "Enter a list of integers: "
DURATION_PROMPT = "Duration: "

def line_break():
    print("")

def play_music():
    notes = raw_input(NOTES_PROMPT)
    duration = raw_input(DURATION_PROMPT)
    map(int, str(notes))
    map(int, str(duration))

for i in range(len(notes)):
    FREQUENCY = int(notes[i]) * 250
    if FREQUENCY == 0:
        FREQUENCY == 100
    line_break()
    print(str(notes[i]))
    winsound.Beep(FREQUENCY, int(duration))

while True:
    play_music()
    line_break()
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Can add you the `if statement` you mentioned you tried to change `0` values to `100`, but it's not working? We don't see the code you tried. That the code raises an error for input `0` is expected follow the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/winsound.html. `The frequency parameter specifies frequency, in hertz, of the sound, and must be in the range 37 through 32,767.`

Comment: @ChristianWill Ok. I added it.

Comment: Remember that = is an assignment operator and == is a comparison operator. `FREQUENCY == 100`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common error is to use a single equal sign `=` instead of a double equal sign `==` or the other way around. Remember that `=` is an assignment operator and `==` is a comparison operator.